# Why the MKScrollContainerView shows displaced in Xcode Debug View Hierarchy?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit

I have an iOS app using the MapKit framework.

The app works fine except that when I go to debug the UI in Xcode using the
`Debug View Hierarchy` I have an `MKScrollContainerView` entirely displaced
(as shown in the attached screenshot).

Any idea on how to fix that `MKScrollContainerView` odd positioning, that makes UI flipping and twisting almost impossible?

[image: Xcode view debugging]

---

**Update 1**

I tested the UI with the Reveal app and a similar issue is present.

[image: Reveal view inspection]

---

**Update 2**

I tried implementing the entire app UI with a Storyboard in InterfaceBuilder
and programmatically, with the same result.

```
class MainViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()
            ...
            self.viewControllers = [Tab1ViewController(), ...]
}

class Tab1ViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()
            ...
            self.pushViewController(MapViewController(), animated: false)
    }
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()

            let mapView = MKMapView()
            mapView.frame = self.view.frame

            self.view.addSubview(mapView)
}
```

Composition:

```
UITabBarController
-> UINavigationController
  -> UIViewController (MapViewController)
    -> MKMapView
```

Comment: If your code is running fine I would not worry about it.  It could just be an Xcode bug.

Comment: The problem arrives when I go to debug the UI, the perspective 3D camera uses as anchor point the middle of the two windows. This has the side effect that when I try to rate my app window, instead of rotating around itself, it rotates around the the middle of the two windows, making impossible to flip or twist the UI.